# HTML 5 Input type date on safari browser

Tags: html, date, cross-browser

I'm using input type date

```
<input type="date" class="form-control " id="StartDateInput">
```

It's working absolutely fine on Chrome but shows empty box in IE and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=date).

Internet Explorer and Safari do not support the `date` type, so they fall back to the default (`text` type).

The behaviour you are seeing is normal.

You could look for or write a JavaScript polyfill for the feature.

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin but could you please provide a solution or workaround my problem.

Comment: @Muddasir23 — See the last paragraph of this answer.